How to get unique field values based on recent and highest priority documents in Elasticsearch?
I have an Elasticsearch index that stores documents with the following fields:

timestamp (date)
priority (integer)
user_id (string)

I need to find 5 unique user_id values from the most recent and highest-priority documents. If I were working with SQL, I would solve this by:
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM documents
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC, priority DESC
) AS sorted_docs
LIMIT 5;


Sorting the data with both timestamp and priority fields in descending order.
Selecting distinct user_id, picking the first 5 from the sorted result.

However, I am unsure how to perform a similar operation in Elasticsearch. I have looked into using terms and composite aggregations, but I'm not clear on:

Ensuring the data is sorted by timestamp and priority before selecting unique user_id.
Limiting the result to the first 5 unique user_id values based on
this sorting.

Can someone guide me on how to structure this query or provide an example? Any help or references would be greatly appreciated!

You have not shared any sample data but based on the information you have given, I have created sample data and provided sample query.
You can use Collapse functionality from Elasticsearch to get distinct value for user_id.
Let consider below is your index mapping:
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "user_id":{
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "timestamp":{
        "type": "date"
      },
     "priority":{
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}

Below is sample data:
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "user_id" : "101", "timestamp" : "2024-11-05T12:10:30Z","priority" : "1"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "user_id" : "101", "timestamp" : "2024-11-05T16:10:30Z","priority" : "2"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "user_id" : "102", "timestamp" : "2024-11-04T12:10:30Z","priority" : "3"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "4" } }
{ "user_id" : "102", "timestamp" : "2024-11-05T08:10:30Z","priority" : "4"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "5" } }
{ "user_id" : "103", "timestamp" : "2024-11-05T12:10:30Z","priority" : "5"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "6" } }
{ "user_id" : "103", "timestamp" : "2024-11-03T12:10:30Z","priority" : "6"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "7" } }
{ "user_id" : "104", "timestamp" : "2024-11-05T12:10:30Z","priority" : "7"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "8" } }
{ "user_id" : "105", "timestamp" : "2024-11-04T12:10:30Z","priority" : "8"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "9" } }
{ "user_id" : "105", "timestamp" : "2024-11-01T12:10:30Z","priority" : "9"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "10" } }
{ "user_id" : "106", "timestamp" : "2024-11-02T12:10:30Z","priority" : "10"}

You can use below query which will sort on timestamp and priority as well as collapse on user_id which will make sure you will get all the unique user ids:
POST test/_search
{
  "size": 5, 
  "sort": [
    {
      "timestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "priority": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ], 
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "user_id"
  }
}

Below will be response for above query:
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 10,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "user_id": "101",
          "timestamp": "2024-11-05T16:10:30Z",
          "priority": "2"
        },
        "fields": {
          "user_id": [
            "101"
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          1730823030000,
          2
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_id": "7",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "user_id": "104",
          "timestamp": "2024-11-05T12:10:30Z",
          "priority": "7"
        },
        "fields": {
          "user_id": [
            "104"
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          1730808630000,
          7
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "user_id": "103",
          "timestamp": "2024-11-05T12:10:30Z",
          "priority": "5"
        },
        "fields": {
          "user_id": [
            "103"
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          1730808630000,
          5
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "user_id": "102",
          "timestamp": "2024-11-05T08:10:30Z",
          "priority": "4"
        },
        "fields": {
          "user_id": [
            "102"
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          1730794230000,
          4
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_id": "8",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "user_id": "105",
          "timestamp": "2024-11-04T12:10:30Z",
          "priority": "8"
        },
        "fields": {
          "user_id": [
            "105"
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          1730722230000,
          8
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

I have consider 10 as highest priority as you didn't clarified in your question. If you want 1 as highest priority then change priority order to asc from desc in sort.
